# How do you check to see which friends are online without leaving the game?

Tags: xbox-one

On the Xbox One, how do you check to see which friends are online without leaving the game?

Comment: If (IF) you have a Windows phone, you can set it up to check which of your friends are online. For Xbox One it will only show online but for 360 it shows games as well.
Not "on the One" though.

Comment: "on the One" as well. i just used it earlier today :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double tap the "home" button on the controller, and look at the friends pane.